# does not capture a class in ajax

Tags: ajax

I'm having trouble changing a class with ajax, it works with the boton class but not with the boton_clic_sin class, please, someone who can help me. Thank you

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.btnguardar').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $container = $(this).closest(".container");
    var id_oferta = $container.find(".id_oferta").val();
    var url_img = $container.find(".url_img").val();
    var $boton = $(this).closest('.boton');  
    var $boton_clic_sin = $(this).closest('.boton_clic_sin');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "app/ofertasguardadasController.php",
        data: {
            id_oferta,  
            url_img},       
        success: function(r) {
            if (r==1) {         
            $('.aviso').empty();
            $('.aviso').append('Se agrego a la lista <a href="Las-Ofertas-que-mas-te-gustan"> Ver lista</a>').fadeIn("fast");
            $('.aviso').fadeOut(7000);
            $boton.addClass('deshabilita');
            $boton.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $boton_clic_sin.addClass('.habilita');
            $('.lista').html("Ver lista").fadeIn("slow");
            $('.title_lista').html("Agregado a la lista").fadeIn("slow");



            }

        }
    });
});
```

});

Html

```
<span class="boton_clic_sin">♥</span>
<button id="btnguardar" class="boton btnguardar">♥</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `span` is located just before your `button` you can use [prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) to get that element and use `toggleClass` to add or remove the added class.

**Demo  Code**(I have removed some code which was not needed ) :

```js
$('.btnguardar').on('click', function(e) {
  //find button prev element ->span
  var $boton_clic_sin = $(this).prev();
  //use toggle to add or remove class
  $boton_clic_sin.toggleClass('habilita');

});
```

```css
.habilita {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="boton_clic_sin">♥</span>
<button id="btnguardar" class="boton btnguardar">♥</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, the problem is that I need this to work after the success: function(r) and it must work on dynamic content.

Comment: so did you check above code ? what doesn't work? also can show more html code ?

Answer (score 1):

You can change a class to your `span` element by using this `$('.boton_clic_sin').addClass('habilita');` and `$('.boton_clic_sin').removeClass('habilita');`
Instead of doing this stuff `var $boton_clic_sin = $(this).closest('.boton_clic_sin');`, and a `toggleClass`

**e.g.**

```js
$('.btnguardar').bind('click', function(e) {

    if($('.boton_clic_sin').hasClass('habilita')){
        $('.boton_clic_sin').removeClass('habilita');
    }else{
        $('.boton_clic_sin').addClass('habilita');
    }
    
});
```

```css
.habilita{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="boton_clic_sin">♥</span>
<button id="btnguardar" class="boton btnguardar">♥</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, the problem is that I need this to work after the success: function(r) and it must work on dynamic content.